# Converting trajectory to outer edges polygon

Tags: postgis, polygon, convex-hull, trajectory

Using PostGIS, I'm trying to solve the following problem:

I have trajectory data (coordinates from API query), like on this image:

[image: Raw trajectory]

and want to convert it into polygon, having only outer edges:

[image]

Comment: Create polygon from polyline then union

Comment: @BERA As I'm new to PostGIS, by create polygon, you mean POLYGON((...))? That results invalid polygon, but can be made valid with ST_MakeValid(), but then what?

Answer (score 1):

You may use [ST_ConcaveHull](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.5/ST_ConcaveHull.html) for your purpose: *The concave hull of a geometry represents a possibly concave geometry that encloses all geometries within the set.*

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 - 
`create table tbl2
as SELECT (ST_ConcaveHull (ST_Collect (geom), 0.99)) as geom FROM tbl1`

Option 2 - 1:

`create table tbl2
as SELECT ST_Intersection (a.geom, b.geom) as geom
FROM tbl1 as a, tbl2 as b
WHERE ST_Intersects (a.geom, b.geom);`
 
2: 
`delete from tbl2 WHERE GeometryType (geom) = 'LINESTRING'`

3: Run on tbl2 `ST_DelaunayTriangles`

4: Remove the extra triangles and union over triangles...

Comment: Option 1-very roughly (with buffering) can solve Your problem; Option 2 - is given due to the fact that you have in the figure there are open geometry in the form of a line and this method cuts open lines from processing...